# Erro na aplicacao android ao buscar dados em banco de dados postgreSQL via WebServices com Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-service, postgresql

Primeiramente fiz um WebService Usando axis 2, onde tem a classe conexao com o banco de dados, e a classe com pedidosDAO com o CRUD.
Usando o SoupUI consigo realizar as chamada dos metodos.
Ate ai tudo bem, criei uma aplicação android para consumir esses serviços, porem esta dando erro na hora de mostrar os dados do banco em uma ListView,quando executo aparece (unfortunately XsaladaTeste has stopped), ja tinha feito antes e tinha dado certo mas agora desda vez nao estou conseguindo meu logcat esta bugado e nao esta mostrando os log.
o que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PedidosXsaladaBusca.java**

```
package com.example.xsaladateste;

public class PedidosXsaladaBusca {

    private int id_pedidos;
    private String informacao_adicionais;
    private int mesa;
    private String nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    private String nome_xsalada;
    private double total_a_pagar;

    PedidosXsaladaBusca() {

    }

    PedidosXsaladaBusca(int id_pedidos, String informacao_adicionais, int mesa, String nome_sobrenome_cliente,
            String nome_xsalada, double total_a_pagar) {

        this.id_pedidos = id_pedidos;
        this.informacao_adicionais = informacao_adicionais;
        this.mesa = mesa;
        this.nome_sobrenome_cliente = nome_sobrenome_cliente;
        this.nome_xsalada = nome_xsalada;
        this.total_a_pagar = total_a_pagar;

    }

    public int getId_pedidos() {
        return id_pedidos;
    }

    public void setId_pedidos(int id_pedidos) {
        this.id_pedidos = id_pedidos;
    }

    public String getNome_sobrenome_cliente() {
        return nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    }

    public void setNome_sobrenome_cliente(String nome_sobrenome_cliente) {
        this.nome_sobrenome_cliente = nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    }

    public int getMesa() {
        return mesa;
    }

    public void setMesa(int mesa) {
        this.mesa = mesa;
    }

    public String getInformacao_adicionais() {
        return informacao_adicionais;
    }

    public void setInformacao_adicionais(String informacao_adicionais) {
        this.informacao_adicionais = informacao_adicionais;
    }

    public double getTotal_a_pagar() {
        return total_a_pagar;
    }

    public void setTotal_a_pagar(double total_a_pagar) {
        this.total_a_pagar = total_a_pagar;
    }

    public String getNome_xsalada() {
        return nome_xsalada;
    }

    public void setNome_xsalada(String nome_xsalada) {
        this.nome_xsalada = nome_xsalada;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PedidosXsaladaBusca [id_pedidos=" + id_pedidos + ", informacao_adicionais=" + informacao_adicionais
                + ", mesa=" + mesa + ", nome_sobrenome_cliente=" + nome_sobrenome_cliente + ", nome_xsalada="
                + nome_xsalada + ", total_a_pagar=" + total_a_pagar + "]";
    }

}
```

**PedidosDAO.java**

```
    public class PedidosDAO {

    // Setando Caminhos

    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.1:8080/BancoParaXsalada/services/PedidosDAO?wsdl";
    private static final String nameSpace = "http://xsalada.com.br";

    // referencias ao metodos no SoapUI XML file
    private static final String BUSCAR = "buscarTodos";

    // metodo inserir no banco pelo android usando biblioteca Ksoap2

    public ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> buscarTodos() {

        ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> lista = new ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca>();

        SoapObject buscarTodos = new SoapObject(nameSpace, BUSCAR);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarTodos);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            http.call("urn:" + BUSCAR, envelope);

            Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

            for (SoapObject soapObject : resposta) {
                PedidosXsaladaBusca user = new PedidosXsaladaBusca();

                user.setId_pedidos(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("id_pedidos").toString()));

                user.setInformacao_adicionais(soapObject.getProperty("informacao_adicionais").toString());

                user.setMesa(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("mesa").toString()));

                user.setNome_sobrenome_cliente(soapObject.getProperty("nome_sobrenome_cliente").toString());

                user.setNome_xsalada(soapObject.getProperty("nome_xsalada").toString());

                user.setTotal_a_pagar(Double.parseDouble(soapObject.getProperty("total_a_pagar").toString()));

                lista.add(user);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ListView listaUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaPedidos);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    }

    PedidosDAO dao = new PedidosDAO();
    ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> lista = dao.buscarTodos();

    ArrayAdapter<PedidosXsaladaBusca> adpUser = new ArrayAdapter<PedidosXsaladaBusca>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);
    listaUsuario.setAdapter(adpUser);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido,  nao era erro de codigo fui perceber que estava dando o seguinte erro :  [timestamp - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

entao pesquisei e conseguir resolver. segue abaixo o link que encontrei para resolver o erro:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger